# Moq: Mock interface that inherits from generic interface

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface defined as follows:

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> All();
}
```

Then, I have an interface extending this:

```
public interface IAccountRepository : IBaseRepository<AccountModel>
{
}
```

In my tests, however, when I try to mock the `IAccountRepository` and call setup for `IAccountRepository.All()`, Moq won't allow me to use the `Returns` method to define a result.

```
var mockAccountRepository = new Mock<IAccountRepository>();
mockAccountRepository.Setup(x => x.All()).Returns(...); // "Returns" can't work here for some reason.
```

How can I mock a base method on an interface that inherits from a generic interface?

Comment: What error do you get?  Are you trying to return something other than an `IQueryable<AccountModel>`?

Comment: `Moq won't allow me to use the Returns method to define a result` 
what does that mean? throws an exception, compilation error? You need to be more specific.

Comment: As a side note, I would do some research on returning `IQueryable`s from repositories - it has benefits but creates a LOT of risk.

Comment: Gah - not sure what happened here. It's suddenly working. Must have been a VS fluke....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mockAccountRepository.Setup(x => x.All()).Returns(new List<AccountModel>().AsQueryable());
```

Comment: @DStanley, you're right, I added the `.AsQueryable()`

Comment: This is what I'd tried and for some reason Intellisense and compilation was failing. Started working randomly. I'm chalking it up to a VS fluke.